# A pop-up window pauses the macro during the extraction SAP table into a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, datatable, vbscript, save, sap-gui

I am trying to extract from SAP a table and save it as a spreadsheet, but I get the following pop-up window that pauses the process.
Please note that I have always open the PERSONAL.xlsb workbook.
Below the relevant code and the pop-up message.

Please, I would like your help in order to be able to bypass this pop-up message without stopping the code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDDqU.jpg)

```
Sub SAP_TABLE()

Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NZSE16"
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_TABLE").Text = MainWS ' main table
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_TABLE").caretPosition = 4
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[3]/menu[2]").Select
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[14]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,5]").Selected = False
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,15]").Selected = True
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,10]").Selected = True
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,10]").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI1-LOW").Text = "GR40"
Sheets(CfgWs).Select  ' gia na parei tis imerominies
On Error Resume Next
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI2-LOW").Text = Range("c5") '"01.02.2023"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI2-HIGH").Text = Range("c6") '"28.02.2023"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI2-HIGH").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI2-HIGH").caretPosition = 10
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'load table
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
'create spreadsheet
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 43
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Sheets(CfgWs).Activate
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Range("C10")
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = RefWb
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 8
Session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

'============================================================================
' waiting for SAP download the spreadsheet and open it
'============================================================================
Const TimeOut = 240   ' 2 minutes.
Const Exportfile = "DOWNLOAD.XLSX"

Dim timeCounter As Long
For timeCounter = 1 To TimeOut Step 1
    '======================
    DoEvents  ' gia na kanei paralliles ergasies otan doulebei.
    '======================
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = Exportfile Then
        'MsgBox Exportfile & " downloaded in " & timeCounter & "s."
        Workbooks(RefWb).Activate
            RefWb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
                Sheets(1).Select
                    Range("A1").Select: Selection = "Solution works..."
        Exit For
    End If
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Next timeCounter

If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> Exportfile Then
    MsgBox "A timeout occurred downloading " & Exportfile
End If
'=============================================================================
'here is the end of module
'=============================================================================


End Sub
```

I would like to bypass the pop up window and macro do not stop.

Comment: You might find the answer to your question here. https://poetengineer.postach.io/post/how-to-fix-file-in-use-personal-xlsb-is-locked-for-editing

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful link !! I tried something different, I add some line in the beginning of the code to close PERSONAL.XLSB and I think I did it.